# Making an image appear in ::before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a picture display at the top of my content container but I can't seem to get it to show up... I want it to take up the entire length of the container and be resizable as the page resizes.

At one point I had it appearing but it extended out and off the right edge of the screen, can't remember what I changed to make it disappear tho lol

Any help is appreciated

```css
* {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


.newsHolder {

    display: block;
    height:auto;
    width: 30%;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba(29,1,52,1);
    opacity:0.5;
    color: #01b3ff;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.newsHolder::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/lAxGaPB');
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<html>


<body>

        <div class="newsHolder">

                <h3> Latest News </h3><br>

                <p>test</p>

        </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the height of pseudo element `::before`. Also, you forgot to set [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

See the Snippet below:

```css
* {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


.newsHolder {

    display: block;
    height:auto;
    width: 30%;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba(29,1,52,1);
    opacity:0.5;
    color: #01b3ff;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.newsHolder::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lAxGaPB.png');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>


<body>

        <div class="newsHolder">

                <h3> Latest News </h3><br>

                <p>test</p>

        </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

to display an image in `::before` pseudo element, you will need to display it as a `background-image`

Comment: Ah yes sorry I did originally have it as background-image but changed it based on what I saw in another post and forgot to change it back! I've reverted the change now and still not working :(